# Проблема создания SVG-элемента через JS

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть некий SVG-файл, в котором имеется `<g id="test"></g>`

И нужно добавить в него `<text x="10" y="10">Опа</text>`

Добавляю так:

```
var text = document.createElement('text');
// text.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
text.setAttribute("x", 10);
text.setAttribute("y", 10);

var temp = svgDocument.getElementById("test");
temp.appendChild(text);
```

И этот код даже работает «почти».

Проблема в том, что он добавляет `<text x="10" y="10"></text>` куда нужно, но он существуют только в html-коде. То есть отсутствует привязка к координатам.

Возможно, виноват атрибут xmlns. Он должен быть равен `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` (судя по SVG-файлу).

Если его не задать самому, то он будет равен `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Но даже если явно указать это параметр, что я и пытался сделать (закомментированная строка), проблема не исчезает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавать элемент с пространством имён svg правильно так:

```
var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
```